# How to add more trains?

Tags: simcity-2013

I nearly always see a complaint bubble at my passenger train station complaining of a need to add more trains to the schedule. Unfortunately I can't see anything to do with adding more trains to the schedule. Is there a way to do this? And would adding another train station help?

[image: Add more trains]

Comment: I *think* you can add more stations to get more capacity on a line. I'm not sure of that though

Comment: This should be possible by doing one of two things.  Upgrade the existing train station or add another train station.  If `mizipzor` is right and the train statin cannot be upgraded then your limited to adding another station.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the looks of it I got more trains/tourists by adding another train station at another corner in my city. But I dont have any recorded numbers to back it up.

I've looked but as far as I can tell there is no way to add more trains or otherwise increase the capacity. Editing the train station I see no upgrade, in contrast to the bus terminal where you can add additional buses.

Comment: I gave it a shot and added another train station. The complaints appear to have stopped, so it looks like that's the solution.

Comment: Seems like an oversight to me. Many train stations in real life just add more platforms to accommodate more trains. I don't understand why SC didn't do something similar consider how modular they made everything else.

Comment: @Tater596 I was also suprised that the train station seems like one of the few things thats *not* modular.